# java Queue Interface

Tags: java, interface, queue

I am looking in to the java queue and i stuck in this line
"**Queue implementations generally do not define element-based versions of the equals and hashCode methods but instead inherit the identity-based versions from Object.**"

> 1.need the complete meaning of the above text.
>   2.what is element based versions of the equals and hashcode -- what it refers to ?
>   3.Identity based versions -- what does this mean ?
>   4. is Version belong to class or object / who's version and where it will be ?

**URL :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html**

Answer (score 4):

It means that standard implementations of the `Queue` interface usually don't override `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `Object` class, which means the default implementation of `Object` class is used (i.e. the identity-based version which simply uses `==` for `equals`).

Element based versions of `equals` and `hashCode` would determine if two `Collection`s are equal and calculate `hashCode` based on the elements contained in the `Collection`, which is why it is called "Element based".

For example, `ArrayList` (or actually its super-class `AbstractList`) overrides `equals` in a way that two `List`s are equal to each other if they have the same number of elements and the elements are equal to each other (in the order in which they appear). The `hashCode` is a function of the `hashCode`s of all the elements.

Comment: and about the version i questioned..?

Comment: @Deepaksai By versions they are referring to implementations. `the identity-based versions from Object` are the implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` of the `Object` class.